# Why is the Excel DateDif function returning 0 months for dates between "4/30/2020" and "3/31/2020"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-difference

Microsoft says the DateDif function: `=DATEDIF(A3,B3,"M")` returns the full number of months between those two dates assuming A3 = Starting month and B3 = Ending month.

However, for dates between 4/30/2020 and 3/31/2020, I am getting a value of 0. I was expecting to get a value of 1. DateDif between 3/1/2020 and 5/31/2020 returns 2, while datedif between 4/30/2020 and 5/31/2020 returns 1 - both of which makes sense to me. So why is the DATEDIF between 4/30/2020 and 3/31/2020 returning 0?

Comment: From the [SUPPORT PAGE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c): `Warning: Excel provides the DATEDIF function in order to support older workbooks from Lotus 1-2-3. The DATEDIF function may calculate incorrect results under certain scenarios.`  There is a reason that it is hidden.  It does not work properly in all cases and they are not going to fix it.

Comment: DATEDIF is using the first date to determine the end of month. Since there are more days in your start month than in the end month, it decides a full month has not elapsed. One of its known limitations (albeit not mentioned on the support page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one can create their own version and use vba's `DateDiff`:

```
Function MyDateDif(srt As Date, ed As Date, str As String) As Long
    MyDateDif = DateDiff(str, srt, ed)
End Function
```

Then you would use it:

```
=MyDateDif(A3,B3,"M")
```

Which returns `1` as it should

[image]

Comment: Great answer Scott, but your variables could benefit from a more descriptive name.

Comment: @Luuklag meh, it was just an example and they work in my head.  The OP can call them what ever they want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ROUNDDOWN` and `YEARFRAC` to calculate the result. This will return a decimal and round down to the nearest whole number. I guess the moral of the story is to not use deprecated functions.

```
=ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A3,B3)*12,0)
```